# Evaluate a string like Java code

Tags: java

In Java I have a method:

```
private boolean testFunction(int x){

   // codes goes here..
}
```

Now I have a expression written in file something like:

```
if(testFunction(10)){ return "ok"; }else{ return null;}
```

I am storing this in a `String` variable inside java program and want to execute it like it should execute as Java code:

```
if(testFunction(10)){ return "ok"; }else{ return null;}`
```

Is it possible?

The thing is I have a web application where there are 10+ different kind of form having different kind of fields i.e in some form X,Y,Z is there and X,Y is required....in some form A,B,C is there and C is only required like this.

So instead of writing validation code for each form i wanted to write a expression in XML file and at the time evaluation these expression will execute by single java method and return some value. So in this way I will just have to write expression in XML file.

Comment: Sure. Almost anything is possible. Java doesn't have an `eval()` function, so you'll have to write one. This will not be a trivial undertaking.

Comment: your method `testFunction()` require return type `boolean`, why you return 'ok' / null?

Comment: `@Rafa El` return 'ok' / null is  out of `testFunction()` and somewhere in the code

Comment: I might implement the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Even if you do find a way, make sure to take security concerns into account! Running arbitrary code is very dangerous; you'll need to sandbox the execution somehow, so that the executed code only has access to the specific things you want to expose. It's definitely not a trivial task.

Comment: *"Evaluate a string like Java code"*    Will JavaScript suffice?  Java can support that via. the `ScriptEngine`.  But note carefully the warning of @yshavit.  Someone who is asking 'how?' seems like a newbie, but only experts (no, **gurus**) on security should be allowing the user to run arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Java is a compiled language, it is not interpreted.

There are ways of generating bytecode dynamically in Java, but they are highly involved, and  aren't anywhere close to the concept of `eval(String code)`

Comment: so what are the possible solutions?

Comment: Most likely the solution to the problem you have is *not* "dynamically compile and evaluate arbitrary Java code."  Tell us what the real problem is and most likely we can provide you with a much cleaner answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamic validation for form entries, I'd suggest using RegExp expressions which can be evaluated and matched against form input at runtime.

Unfortunately your OP was a bit vague as to what you're actually trying to achieve.

To get you started: [RegExp Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)